# How to make an alarm live even when the application which set it is killed?

Tags: android, alarm

I have a little confusion with setting an alarm. If anyone could give feedback or some hints it'll be greatly appreciated. In summary here is my situation:

Inside my application I set an alarm:

```
////////////////////////
// Set an alarm

// Actually I set a unique id here. The hardcoded value is for simplicity only.
int id = 123454321;

Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyAlarm.class);
PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, id, intent, 0);

long firstTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
firstTime += 10*1000;

AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, firstTime, 15*1000, sender);
////////////////////////

////////////////////////
// MyAlarm implementation
public class MyAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        // Do some periodic work here
    }
}
////////////////////////
```

When I set the alarm everything is fine and good. I can see my alarm when I use the command:

```
    adb shell dumpsys alarm
```

I can see the alarm even when my application goes to the background.

Next I manually kill my application through

Settings - Applications - Manage applications -  - Force stop

When I re-issue the command "adb shell dumpsys alarm" I see that my alarm is gone. This makes me think that when my application goes into the background and the framework kills it to free resources, my alarm will also be killed. However, I would like to have an alarm which will live independent of whether the application is running or not. Does anybody have hints how to do this?

Comment: considered using service? even then there is a chance that service can be killed, you can give higher priority to service, so that there is a minimum chance of your service being killed.

Comment: Yes, I tried service as well but the service was also killed. I got a comment on this subject from Mark Murphy on another platform and he says that manually stopping an application like this does not simulate OS behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I have an app that sets an alarm and then goes away.

The code I use is:

Manifest:

```
    <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver" android:process=":remote"></receiver>
```

PendingIntent Code:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra("ALARM_MESSAGE", alarmMessage);
    PendingIntent receiverIntent =
        PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
        MyConstants.UPDATE_ALARM, intent,
        pendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Set (actually cancel old and reset):

```
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.cancel(receiverIntent); // get rid of previous if unfired.
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calcTime.afterMidnight(), receiverIntent);
```

The pendingIntent fires the receiver, the receiver does some quick work , sends a notification, and goes away.  The receiver doesn't have to post a notification. It can start an activity with an intent, do a toast message, etc.

I have a receiver that restores the alarm after a boot. (The alarm does go away at power down.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried it, but the alarm is still being removed after  Settings - Applications - Manage applications - <MyApp> - Force stop

Comment: A force stop will shut down everything. It is what used to be called an abend in the old days. ABnormal END. When you force stop through the settings, you are telling the Android operating system that the app has a major problem and you want it ripped out completely. Is there a problem with your app? If not, you need to exit normally using finish().

Comment: PS: I missed the fact you were forcing stop on my first read.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I was trying to simulate the case when the framework kills an application to free resources. However, as it appears, "Force stop" does not simulate this case.

Comment: You will have two main routines (there are more, but usually unneeded) that will be hit. The onPause and the onStop. You can test onPause by hitting the Home key. The on stop can be tested by doing a finish() in your mainline. Quit button for example. You can use log.d to trace and make sure they worked in an emulator. Temporary toast messages on a device.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your receiver object has not been registered in the manifest. If you registered the receiver object in the manifest file then the system will find it and call even if your application's not running.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but I registered the receiver in the manifest. I have the line <receiver android:name=".MyAlarm" /> in the manifest file. Apparently, after manually stopping an application all alarms and services started by that application are also removed.